# How to display business on embedded google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to include a business on to my embedded map, however I could not do it for my life! :D

This is what I got so far:

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 47.7914, lng: 22.87691};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYMAPAPIlanguage=hu&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

and I want to include this business:
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Boitor+Orsolya,+Cabinet+Medical+Individual/@47.7914061,22.8747236,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x473805cc6d46a92d:0x18460661870adb34!2sBoitor+Orsolya,+Cabinet+Medical+Individual!8m2!3d47.7914061!4d22.8769123!3m4!1s0x473805cc6d46a92d:0x18460661870adb34!8m2!3d47.7914061!4d22.8769123

All I can find online is using iframes, which I would avoid because of speed.
thanks

As a reference, this is what I want to achieve without iframes:
[image]

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps API get place text like on iframe map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274487/google-maps-api-get-place-text-like-on-iframe-map) (the red text on the map, but not the white box with text, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is to add your desired coordinates to add a marker and to center the map. Like here. You can also add a infoWindow to describe a little more what is on that place.

```
  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.791846, 22.876955), // <--- I found these are the coordinates for the place you mentioned
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*
   * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
   */
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2267/) to see the map running

Comment: thanks. It's getting there, but it's still not what I try to achieve. :( I have updated the question with a reference image of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use infoWindow

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
        center: {lat: lat, lng: lng}, //location of the map center
        zoom: 6
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    //Location of your object
    var pos = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    };

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Business'); //Name of the infowindow
```

Here is what it would look like
[image]

Comment: thanks. I will use as a backup, I am trying to achieve something like here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide